# Initializing an array of empty vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to create an array of empty string vectors, but I can't manage to initialize the vectors to be able to push values into them:

```
vector <string> v[500];
// vector initializing code
v[0].push_back("hello"); // should work now
```

Error message is:

```
'v' does not name a type
```

How should I initialize so that v[0].push_back() works?

Comment: What isn't working for you at the moment? Your current problem description is unclear. **EDIT:** Your code works as is. Demo: [here](https://ideone.com/fLXQ82).

Comment: Does `v[0].push_back("hello");` not work?  If so, how so?

Comment: That should work. `vector <string> v[500]` should initialize vectors to empty.

Comment: Nothing to do, vector will be initialize correctly ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dca3bb0eb954d8cf)). By, why not using vector of vector ? (`vector<vector<string>> v(500)`)

Comment: Or better, if size is known at compime-time : `std::array<std::vector<string>, 500> v;`

Comment: Regarding the update with error message, did you `#include` relevant headers?

Comment: According your edit, your issue isn't with vector initialization, but with declaration! have you include `vector` ? `string` ? have you somewhere `using namespace std;` ?

Comment: I'm placing my bet on `v[0].push_back("hello");` not being inside a function.

Comment: +Garf365 I considered vector of vectors but I wanted to know why array of vector's doesn't work, +Algirdas Preidzius, +Garf365 all #include are included as is using namespace std

Comment: Also, while you're at it, remove that `using namespace std;`. It's a horribly bad practice.

Comment: @byrass is `v[0].push_back("hello");` written inside a `main` function?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidzius no, it's outside

Comment: vector has  dynamically allocated memory why it should have size in initialization ?

Comment: @byrass So, that's your problem. You cannot have executable code outside of functions. If you are having these sorts of problems, I suggest you read a book on C++.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidzius thanks, works perfectly! +Quentin on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in all the comments on your question, your error occurs because you wrote your code out of a `main` function. Each C++ program must have it.

By the way, here are good practices for free (found also in comments).

- Use `std::array` instead of C-array if you know the size at compile-time (and I believe you do).
- Avoid `using namespace std;` because [it's bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4043963/6060256).
- Be sure that you do well all your includes : `#include <string>`, `#include <vector>` and `#include <array>` if using-so.
- If you're a C++ beginner, I suggest [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321714113), updated for C++11. If your a complete beginner, [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321992784).