# multiple "using namespace" in a line?

Tags: c++

I searched but I could not find related question.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

In my project I use the following:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
```

I want it to be like below.

```
using namespace std, sf;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write some ugly macros. I wouldn't put myself on that job though.

Comment: @DeiDei Yeah, that's a horrible idea :P.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This syntax is **not** supported, so you'll have to keep declaring multiple `using` statements.

In general, though, it's considered best practice to avoid declaring `using namespace` at all - definitely not in headers, and preferably in the inner-most scope possible (as to not pollute too much scope with unwanted symbols.

Answer (score 3):

> I want it to be like below.
>
> ```
> using namespace std, sf;
> ```

The syntax you're after is simply not supported by the current c++ standard.

Besides it is [discouraged to import whole namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043930/is-using-namespace-like-bad) (at least not in header files), you may sent a request to the [c++ standards committee](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee), and see if they like to support that.

---

The general advice is that you should only

- either specify exact classes you're using in your translation unit (to save typing) like `using std::cout = co;`
- or to make everything clear by explicitly using fully qualified identifiers everywhere like `std::cout`, `std::endl`, etc.

The latter way is the most readable and best IMO.